# How to do a Sigma in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to make a calculator for something, but the formulas use a sigma, I have no idea how to do a sigma in python, is there an operator for it?
Ill put a link here with a page that has the formulas on it for illustration:http://fromthedepths.gamepedia.com/User:Evil4Zerggin/Advanced_cannon

Comment: I am not familiar with that form of sigma notation. Isn't there supposed to be a little "i=<number>" under the Σ?

Comment: @Kevin I'm not sure which of the many formulas on that page the OP means, but if it's sigma notation, if no indices are provided, the sum is understood to be over some expected range inferred from context. OP: look at Python's `sum` command.

Answer (score 2):

Captial sigma (Σ) applies the expression after it to all members of a range and then sums the results.

In Python, `sum` will take the sum of a range, and you can write the expression as a comprehension:

For example
[Speed Coefficient](https://fromthedepths.fandom.com/wiki/Advanced_Cannon#Speed_Coefficient)

> A factor in muzzle velocity is the speed coefficient, which is a
> weighted average of the speed modifiers s<sub>i</sub> of the (non-
> casing) parts, where each component i starting at the head has half the
> weight of the previous:
>
> [image: s={\frac {\sum 0.75^{i}s_{i}}{\sum 0.75^{i}}}}]
>
> The head will thus always determine at least 25% of the speed
> coefficient.
>
> For example, suppose the shell has a Composite Head (speed modifier
> 1.6), a Solid Warhead Body (speed modifier 1.3), and a Supercavitation
> Base (speed modifier 0.9). Then we have
>
> s<sub>0</sub>=1.6
>
> s<sub>1</sub>=1.3
>
> s<sub>2</sub>=0.9
> [image: s={\frac {0.75^{0}\cdot 1.6+0.75^{1}\cdot 1.3+0.75^{2}\cdot 0.9}{0.75^{0}+0.75^{1}+0.75^{2}}}\approx 1.33}]

From the example we can see that *i* starts from 0 not the usual 1 and so we can do

```py
def speed_coefficient(parts):
    return (
        sum(0.75 ** i * si for i, si in enumerate(parts))
        /
        sum(0.75 ** i for i, si in enumerate(parts))
    )
```

```
>>> speed_coefficient([1.6, 1.3, 0.9])
1.3324324324324326
```

Answer (score 0):

A sigma (∑) is a [Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation) operator. It evaluates a certain expression many times, with slightly different variables, and returns the **sum** of all those expressions.

For example, in the [Ballistic coefficient](http://fromthedepths.gamepedia.com/User:Evil4Zerggin/Advanced_cannon#Ballistic_coefficient) formula

[image]

The Python implementation would look something like this:

```
# Just guessing some values. You have to search the actual values in the wiki.
ballistic_coefficients = [0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.9, 0.1]

total_numerator = 0
total_denominator = 0
for i, coefficient in enumerate(ballistic_coefficients):
    total_numerator += 2**(-i) * coefficient
    total_denominator += 2**(-i)
print('Total:', total_numerator / total_denominator)
```

You may want to look at the [`enumerate` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate), and beware precision problems.

Answer (score 0):

An efficient way to do this in Python is to use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

To solve

```
3
Σ i
i=1
```

You can use the following:

```
from functools import reduce
result = reduce(lambda a, x: a + x, [0]+list(range(1,3+1)))
print(result)
```

`reduce()` will take arguments of a callable and an iterable, and return one value as specified by the callable.  The accumulator is `a` and is set to the first value (`0`), and then the current sum following that.  The current value in the iterable is set to `x` and added to the accumulator.  The final accumulator is returned.

The formula to the right of the sigma is represented by the lambda.  The sequence we are summing is represented by the iterable.  You can change these however you need.

For example, if I wanted to solve:

```
Σ π*i^2
i
```

For a sequence I `[2, 3, 5]`, I could do the following:

```
reduce(lambda a, x: a + 3.14*x*x, [0]+[2,3,5])
```

You can see the following two code lines produce the same result:

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, x: a + 3.14*x*x, [0]+[2,3,5])
119.32
>>> (3.14*2*2) + (3.14*3*3) + (3.14*5*5)
119.32
```

Comment: `reduce()` is overkill. Use `sum()` instead. `sum(range(1, 3+1)`; `sum(3.14*x**2 for x in [2, 3, 5])`

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to create a sigma function the returns the summation, you can barely understand this, you don't need to use a library. you just need to understand the logic .

```py
def sigma(first, last, const):
    sum = 0
    for i in range(first, last + 1):
        sum += const * i
    return sum

# first : is the first value of (n) (the index of summation)
# last : is the last value of (n)
# const : is the number that you want to sum its multiplication each (n) times with (n)
```

Comment: This is overkill. Just use `sum()` with a generator expression: `sum(const*i for i in range(first, last+1)`.

Comment: Also, beside the point, but `sum` is a bad variable name since it [shadows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) the [builtin `sum()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum). You could use a name like `total` instead, although it's a moot point if you just use `sum()` itself, like I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I've looked all the answers that different programmers and coders have tried to give to your query but i was unable to understand any of them maybe because i am a high school student anyways according to me using LIST will definately reduce some pain of coding so here it is what i think simplest way to form a sigma function .

```
#creating a sigma function
a=int(input("enter a number for sigma  "))
mylst=[]

for i in range(1,a+1):
     mylst.append(i)
     b=sum(mylst)
print(mylst)
print(b)
```

Comment: The list isn't needed. `print(sum(range(1, a + 1)))` will already print the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think that to use 'SIGMA' in python3 , it's quit simple :
Don't forget that we have the "range" function in python The range() function returns a sequence of numbers, starting from 0 by default, and increments by 1 (by default), and stops before a specified number.

The syntax:

```
range(start, stop, step)
```

[image]

and as we see in the picture we understand that sigma it's like range in python

however I explore this theory some time and i found the secret formula of sigma :

```py
counter = 0
sigma = list(range(0, 100, 2))
for item in sigma:
    counter = counter + item
    print(counter)
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try this code

```
import numpy as np

def sigma(s,e,x):
  return np.sum([x + i - 1 for i in range(s,e+1)])
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. This is particularly important when answering old questions (this one is nearly 7 years old) with existing answers. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked, and how it improves upon what is already here. See [answer].