# How to perform sigma operations for a particular case?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried to get help from this question: [How to do a Sigma in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33422534/how-to-do-a-sigma-in-python-3/55982117) and this is not a duplicate question.There are no answers in the previous question.

I want to use this expression in python:
[image]

For this, I have tried:

```
N = 2
Vk = 170
F1k = 5
F2k = 10
C1 = 3
C2 = 5
```

I tried using:

```
from functools import reduce

sigma1 = reduce(lamda a, x:a+....
```

I am confused with what to write in .... missing part for this equation

Comment: I would assume that `F_ik` and `C_i` would be vectors (or functions taking `i` as an input), and not constants, right? In that case you'd do something along the lines of `sum((F_k[i] * C[i] / V_k) for i in range(1, N +1))`

Comment: so, if ` F_ik and C_i ` are vectors, then , `F_k[i] and c[i] ` values should be in list??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
N = 2
Vk = 170
F1k = 5
F2k = 10
C1 = 3
C2 = 5

Fk = [F1k, F2k]
C = [C1, C2]

sigma1 = sum(Fk[i]*C[i]/Vk for i in range(N))
print(sigma1)
```

Here `Fk` and `C` are lists so you can index them to access the corresponding `Fik` and `Ci` values.

This prints the following:

```
0.3823529411764706
```

Comment: Worth noting that `i` is one lower than in the math version: `i=0 ... N-1`

Comment: @wjandrea Right, the list indices are zero-based and as you say, one lower than that in the problem spec.

Answer (score 0):

Use numpy:

```
import numpy as np

Vk = 170
Fk = np.array([5, 10])
C = np.array([3, 5])

sigma1 = (Fk*C/Vk).sum()
```